# Problems compiling/executing GDAL in C++

Tags: c++, terminal, gdal

I am working on a MacOS, and have just installed GDAL. Now when I type in the terminal

`gdal-config --libs`

I get

`-L/anaconda2/lib -lgdal`,

and if I type

`gdal-config --cflags`

I get

`-I/anaconda2/include`.

Now when I compile my program as

```
  g++ myprogram.cpp -L/anaconda2/lib -lgdal -I/anaconda2/include -o myprogram
  ./myprogram
```

I get this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.20.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/ducciopiovani/Desktop/WORK_NAMR/polygon_features_c++/./myprogram
Reason: Incompatible library version: myprogram requires version 24.0.0 or later, but libgdal.20.dylib provides version 23.0.0
Abort trap: 6
```

Now I had trouble installing GDAL, therefore I hav tried everything I could and perhaps installed it several times. Can I get any help on how to get this program running ?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Duccio, it looks like your installation is broken. In fact, the linker is complaining about a version mismatch.

How did you install GDAL? I suggest you to use the prebuilt frameworks provided [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).